# Interface Builder UIButton with Image Rounded Corners Gone

Tags: uibutton, rounded-corners

Using Interface Builder I have a UIView with a number of UIButtons as subviews. In IB all of the button types are set to Rounded Rect and each button uses an image from the image drop down box. The images are square and the size of the rounded rect UIButton is the same as image. The images are png's and they are from b&w photo's.

The issue is the UIButton rounded corners are gone and everything is square in IB and when running under the simulator.(no hardware yet) I was hoping the button drawRect would crop the image and preserve the rounded rect look. Is there a way to do this? in IB?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Clip Subviews are checked in IB. It's in the Attributes Inspector under the  View section.

Comment: for now, seems like viewDidLoad is the only solution that works:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8627925/474330

Comment: and make sure that "Clip Subviews" is checked under View > Drawing in Attributes Inspector