# How to create a customized rounded UiView and UIButton like MobilePASS?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I want to create a similar UIView with rounded corner and UIButton just like this app.
Can I implement this on Interface Builder?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can round the corners and set a border in code, just make sure you have QuartzCore framework included.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.welcomeView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.welcomeView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.welcomeView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

}
```

Then just lay out your views and setup your outlets in IB.  That should get you going, lots of cool stuff in Quartz.

Here is a link to the API reference http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500

Comment: Jerry!! does that UIButton, Active No", also use QuartzCore framework to achieve "Green and glassy" style??

Comment: I didn't develop it but I would say that is probably an image they are using.  You know how on a UIButton you can call [button setImage: forState:].  They probably have a set of assets for normal state and pressed.  That's where it's handy to have a designer :)

Comment: Looks like you are new to StackOverflow.  Don't forget to mark a response as answer, preferably mine, if you feel it answered your question ;)

Comment: Jerry. I've make the rounded corner by QuartzCore framework. Very thanks your sample code. It's a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons) tutorial by Ray Wenderlich.